# How I can Update row during insert MySQL?

Tags: mysql, arrays, insert

I have table with following stucture:

```
NUMBER  NAME
122222  AAAA
222323  BBBB
343434  CCCC
443434  DDDD
```

I want to insert new records from array but If number match I want to update NAME.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 122222          
    [1] => AAAABB   
)
```

The NUMBER is PK.
Is there any way this can happen only with MySQL ?

I apologize for my english.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can try ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax`. Check this link [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: If I have a new element in the array, which is not in the table will be inserted in a table?

Comment: yes. only if duplicate key is found, it will follow the update part

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE into table (NUMBER, NAME) values(122222, 'AAAABB')
```